# Can I add buttons to sections of grouped tableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a grouped tableView with 5 sections and i want to add buttons per sections. 
For example i have add (+) button in all sections near the section title.

Can i do that?

Regards,
ZaldzBugz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` method in table's delegate and create custom view for section header there with title and button (and with whatever else you need).